# Question about temperature of car

Tags: engine

In my auto (Škoda Rapid 1.6 Diesel 115 HP 2015) show in display " Check outside temperature " Is it danger something?Is it necassary to check in car service?

Comment: But when I put for first time the key inside always show that for a moment and then disappear and the night also at the day when is son shining !

Answer (score 1):

I concur with mike's answer hat it's a warning of low external temperatures making road icing more likely, and wish to add that in these cases you may also see an indicator like a snowflake in the display. The temperature the indicator appears at varies between manufacturers but most cars warn of low temperature when then external temperature is between 2 and 4 degrees C

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the outside temperature is close to freezing - leading to the risk of black ice.

Unless this is listed as a fault condition where the car is not getting that particular reading.